# What's the difference between vanity and boastfullness?

Tags: aristotle, virtue-ethics

In Aristotle's Nicomachean Ethics the vices boastfulness and vanity are described. The explanations (English translations, Leob) I have found are that vanity is "claiming more than you deserve" and boastfulness is "exaggerating what you have esp. to gain something". But to me these explanations overlap because "exaggerating what you have" sounds to me like "claiming more than you deserve". Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: i upvoted, it's a good question i cannot answer beyond my impromptu opinion that boastfulness is more aggressive and more likely to lead to just your own downfall, as it's easier to see through and less personal, i guess?

Comment: One can be vain in one's appearance, but to be boastful requires an exercise in language. Vanity is something one suffers in the mind, because it is possible to conceal being vain, but one necessarily must share with communication a boast. Furhtermore, boasting might be deserved. For instance, after the World Cup in Soccer, the winner has earned the right to boast they're the best team in the world; they're both a deviation from humility, but in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to invoke Habermas and point out that these two vices represent different modes of reasoning.

- 'Vanity' falls under what Habermas would call the 'dramaturgical' mode: a claim meant to convince others on the grounds of the speaker's sincerity
- 'Boastfulness' is under what he would call the 'teleological' mode: a claim offered not for its truth-value but because it is a useful assertion in the pursuit of some other goal

For example, say somebody in a bar says "I'm the greatest baseball player around"; we'll call that statement a performative linguistic act. That act would be 'vanity' if the aim of the performance is to spread the speaker's sincere belief to others so they hold it as well; it would be 'boastfulness' if the aim of the performance is to get something from others (a romantic hook-up, a free beer or two, a rise out of an opponent across the room...).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in the days of Aristotle the words had other connotations, but in modern English the key difference between the two words (the meanings of which overlap) is that boasting is a form of communication- you boast to others, whereas vanity can be purely introspective.